# How to remove brackets and number from the beginning of an expression

Tags: java, regex

If I have a string with brackets at the beginning of the expression, how would I go about of removing them along with the number using regex.
For example
I have 
String A:

`"(1) Hi How are you (2).`

and I want it to look like this:
String B:

> `Hi How Are you (2).`

I tried using

> string.replaceAll("^\p{P}","");

but that only did this:

> 1) Hi How are you (2).

It removed only the first bracket in the expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
string = string.replaceFirst("^\\s*\\(\\d*\\)\\s*", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yY6rD3/1)

**Explanation:**

```
^     # match line start
\\s*  # match 0 or more spaces
\\(   # match left (
\\d*  # match 0 or more digits
\\)   # match right )
\\s*  # match 0 or more spaces
```

Replacement is by empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.replaceFirst` function.

```
String s =  "(1) Hi How are you (2)";
System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("^\\([^)]*\\)\\s*", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
Hi How are you (2)
```